# Show new page in AngularJS on list view item select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, listview

I have a cross platform app developed using AngularJS, Monaca and Onsen UI.

In one of my views I display a listview similar to the **List Item with Chevron** on [THIS](http://components.onsen.io/) page of Onsen UI.

This list is built dynamically with data from my Database and displays a list of dates. I can populate the list and display the dates in the list using ng-repeat.

When the user selects any of the dates from the list, I need to capture what list item (date) has been selected. I also need to navigate to the next page where I use the reference as to what date was selected to show the user further information regardng that date.

How do I capture what date item was selected and save this as well as navigate to the next screen?

This is how I have my view listview built at the moment where I repeat the data and do a pushPage() when the user selects on of the list items. But how do I get what list item was selected so I can save this for use on my next view.

```
<ul class="list">
    <li ng-repeat="myDate in data" class="list__item list__item--chevron" ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('date-details.html', {animation: 'slide'});")>
        {{myDate.date}}  
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Call a function on your controller when a list item is clicked and pass the date into it. e.g. `ng-click="dateClicked(myDate)"`

Comment: I already have a ng-click that pushes a new page Can I have 2 ng-clicks?

Comment: Just handle everything from the `dateClicked()` function. e.g. you can push the new page from there too

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding i think you can pass {{myDate.date}} inside function on ng-click event and use it inside that functions defination...

Hope it will help you... :)